# Choose email subject from dropdown list of excel column

Tags: vba, excel, email, combobox

I have code for emails and I want to connect to a column in an excel. When the macro is triggered, a dropdown should appear so I can choose to how to send the email depending on a list in an excel. The list is generated from other excels, it could have 2 full names or 40 full names. The list is in Sheet4 and the names are in column L, the email address is in column Q and the text in column P. If I choose from the dropdown, the name in L2, it should take the email address from Q2, the name from L2 and the text from P2. Here is what I have until now:

```
Sub email_to_one_person_from_the_list()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim sourceWB As Object
Dim sourceWS As Object

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    strFile = "C:\persons.xlsm" 

    Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)
    Set sourceWH = sourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    sourceWB.Activate

sourceWH.Application.Run "Module2.FetchData3"

     On Error Resume Next
     Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     On Error GoTo 0

     Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
     With OutMail
         .To = sourceWH.Range("Q2").Value
         .CC = ""
         .BCC = ""
         .Subject = "Dear " & sourceWH.Range("L2").Value
         .Display
         OutMail.HTMLBody = sourceWH.Range("P2").Value

   sourceWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
   xlApp.Quit

     Set OutMail = Nothing
     Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

and the combobox:

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
 Unload Me
 End
End Sub
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    thelist1 = ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ComboBox1 
             ' the  excel list here
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you use a form to select from the dropdown? or where should it be?

Comment: it should be a userform but i don't find how to connect a userform from outlook to a dynamic column from excel. i can make an userform but i don't have the code for it .

Comment: Which application does the macro reside in? Excel, Outlook?

Comment: The macro is in outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP's usage of my original code and further clarifications

here follows a complete refactoring code as per the following "rules"

- `Option Explicit`statement

  this forces you to declare all variables

  but this little extra work but earns you back with much more control over what your writing and less debugging and/or maintenance efforts
- main "mega" code splitting into many single Sub/Funcs

  this helps in

  - have more readable and maintainable code
  - keeping Userforms and Applications loading and unloading calls away from any UserForm code, which must only take care of its real work: gather information

place this in your Outlook Module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub email_DP2()

Dim mailData As Variant

mailData = GetMailDataFromExcel("C:\persons.xlsm", _
                                      "Module2.FetchData3", _
                                      "Sheet4", _
                                      "L")
If mailData = Empty Then Exit Sub

With CreateItem(0)
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .Importance = olImportanceHigh
    .To = mailData(1)
    .Subject = mailData(0)
    .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.collapse 1
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = mailData(2)
    '.Paste 'what are you pasting from?
End With

End Sub


'-------------------------------------------------------
' Excel handling Subs and Funcs
'-------------------------------------------
Function GetMailDataFromExcel(strFile As String, fetchingModule As String, strSheet As String, colStrng As String) As Variant
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim closeExcel As Boolean
    Dim namesRng As Excel.Range

    Set xlApp = GetExcel(closeExcel)

    If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set namesRng = GetExcelRange(xlApp, strFile, fetchingModule, strSheet, colStrng) 'this will get the names range from given column of given worksheet of given workbook
        With UserForm14
            If namesRng.Count = 1 Then
                .ComboBox1.AddItem namesRng.Value
            Else
                .ComboBox1.List = xlApp.Transpose(namesRng)
            End If
            .Show
            With .ComboBox1
                If .ListIndex > -1 Then GetMailDataFromExcel = Array(.Value, _
                                             namesRng.Offset(, 5).Cells(.ListIndex + 1, 1).Value, _
                                             namesRng.Offset(, 6).Cells(.ListIndex + 1, 1).Value)
            End With
        End With
        Unload UserForm14
        Set namesRng = Nothing
        ReleaseExcel xlApp, closeExcel
    End If

End Function


Function GetExcelRange(xlApp As Excel.Application, strFile As String, fetchingModule As String, strSheet As String, colStrng As String) As Excel.Range
    With xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)
        xlApp.Run fetchingModule
        With .Worksheets(strSheet)
            Set GetExcelRange = .Columns(colStrng).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, colStrng).End(xlUp).Row)
        End With
    End With
End Function


Function GetExcel(closeExcel As Boolean) As Excel.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If GetExcel Is Nothing Then
        Set GetExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        closeExcel = True
    End If
    If GetExcel Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't instantiate Excel!", vbCritical
    End If
End Function


Sub ReleaseExcel(xlApp As Excel.Application, closeExcel As Boolean)
    If closeExcel Then xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------
```

place this in your UserForm14 code pane

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

in this latter I

- added `Option Explicit` statement

  although not strictly necessary (there is no variables usage but "built in" ones), it builds on a good habit
- added a `UserForm_QueryClose`event handler

  that handles the possible user's clicking the UserForm "Close" button
- erased the `End` statement

  I always learned it's a bad habit to use it and better stick to `Exit Sub`/`Exit Function` ones (possibly with proper mix of  `If.. Then.. Else` blocks) to achieve the same effect without any harm

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to format properly from my smartphone.

Comment: I saw you accepted another solution. Do you still need further elaborations on my answer? The error is due to UserForm code unloading itself and thus not making choices made available to code following it. I believe both handling the "birth" of a new application (Excel) and the closing of a UserForm should be kept away from the UserForm code and placed in its calling code. Should you agree you want to substitute any UserForm `Unload Me` statement  with `Me.Hide` and add `Unload UserForm1` after my code last `End With`.There remains possible "close "button" users's clicking to handle.

Comment: That's precisely it: have UserForm being "exploited" by the caller code who'd take care of all "pre" and "post" fuss and have UserForm do its dirty work only (gather information). Should you need any further clarification, just ask for them. If you found my answer useful, you may want to up-vote it...

Comment: as for the "Type mismatch" error in `.ComboBox1.AddItem namesRng.Value`: query data in `namesRng` (it should be a one cell range, since you get there after `If namesRng.Count = 1` returns `True`). Actually  `.Value` property of `Range` object returns a `Variant` while `.AddItem` method of `.ListBox` object requires a `String` type. Maybe in my "environment" that conversion is made under the hood... try substituting `namesRng.Value` with `CStr(namesRng.Value)`

Comment: most probably the macro execution was stopped before total completion at least once. from then on there lingers at least 1 active Excel application which gets caught at the subsequent call of `GetExcel`. You could rectify this situation in two ways 1) close all application and restart your PC. and from then on make sure the macro _always_ gets to call ReleaseExcel (throw in some error handling labels) 2) from the immediate window type `Set myExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` and, if no errors are notified, type in `myExcel.Visible=True` and switch to Excel and close it. and loop...

Comment: Hi, the persons.xlsm remains open after i run the macro. I have tried to close after the execution of the macro but it just doesn't close (or i didn't do something good) . i can close the persons.xlsm with task manager so when i run the macro the message "persons.xlsm is open , reopen persons.xlsm?" will not appear. is there a way to just close the file after macro execution? Thank you.

Comment: To close a workbook you want to use the `.Close()` method of the `Workbook` object  (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838613.aspx)). In this case you may want to close the workbook in `ReleaseExcel` Sub by adding `xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)` as its first statement

Comment: Did you get through it?

Comment: Hi, i have tested and it works. Thank you for you support.

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the solution you adopted you may want to mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To connect your Outlook to Excel, you first have to add a reference to "Microsoft Excel XX Object Library" where XX is some version number (Extras->References)

Then create a userform, mine looks like this:
[image: example userform]

Note that my combobox has 2 columns (first one has a width of 0 so it's invisible)

Then, when you are loading the Form, add code to open an Excel instance and load the combobox with values to select from:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Define Excel-Variables
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

'Create Excel Instance
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

'Make it invisible
xlApp.Visible = False

'Open Workbook with Values
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("PATH TO YOUR EXCEL FILE")

'Select the Sheet with Values
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Worksheets("sheet1")

Dim i As Integer

'Loop through the Values
For i = 1 To 30 Step 1

    'This Combobox has 2 Columns where 1 is the bound one
    'Add RowIndex to the first column(will be used to find the values later)
    Me.cboTest.AddItem i

    'Add the Name to the second Column
    Me.cboTest.List(Me.cboTest.ListCount - 1, 1) = xlSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i

'Clean up and close Excel
Set xlSheet = Nothing

xlWB.Close False

xlApp.Quit

Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then you need to add some code to the button:

Private Sub cmdSend_Click()

```
'variables for the values we are getting now
Dim name As String, email As String, text As String

'more excel variables
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet


Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlApp.Visible = False

Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("PATH TO EXCEL FILE")

Set xlSheet = xlWB.Worksheets("sheet1")


'access the rowindex from the first column of the combobox
'use it for the Cells() as row
'column may be edited as needed
name = xlSheet.Cells(Me.cboTest.List(Me.cboTest.ListIndex, 0), 1).Value
email = xlSheet.Cells(Me.cboTest.List(Me.cboTest.ListIndex, 0), 2).Value
text = xlSheet.Cells(Me.cboTest.List(Me.cboTest.ListIndex, 0), 3).Value

'excel cleanup
Set xlSheet = Nothing

xlWB.Close False

xlApp.Quit

Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

'print output to console
'instead of this, write your email
Debug.Print "mailto:" & email & " name:" & name & " text: " & text
End Sub
```

Then, if we open the form, we can select from the values:
[image: selection example]

If we then click the button, it will open excel and get the relevant values of the item we have selected.

Output for Name5 looks like this:
[image: console output]

By the way, my excel example list looks like this:

[image: exel example list]

Answer (score 0):

@user3598756

I made the config with your code:

userform14 code:"

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
 Me.Hide
 End
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub
```

[image]

and the function code:

```
    Sub email_DP2()
    Dim name As String, email As String, text As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim olInsp As Object
    Dim oRng As Object
    Dim StrBdB As String

        Dim xlApp As Object
        Dim sourceWB As Object
        Dim sourceWS As Object
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        strFile = "C:\persons.xlsm" 
        Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)
        Set sourceWH = sourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet4")
        sourceWH.Application.Run "Module2.FetchData3"

    Dim pickedName As String, emailAddress As String, emailText As String
    Dim namesRng As Range

    With sourceWH '<== change "myWorkbookName" and "Sheet4" to your needs
        Set namesRng = .Range("L1:L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    With UserForm14 ' change it to whatever name your actual UserForm has
        .ComboBox1.List = xlApp.Transpose(namesRng)
        .Show
        With ComboBox1
             pickedName = .Value
             emailAddress = namesRng.Offset(, 5).Cells(.ListIndex + 1, 1).Value
             emailText = namesRng.Offset(, 6).Cells(.ListIndex + 1, 1).Value
        End With
    End With
Unload UserForm14
         On Error Resume Next
         Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
         If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
         On Error GoTo 0
         Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
         With OutMail
             OutMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
             .Importance = olImportanceHigh
             .To = emailAddress  
             .Subject = pickedName 
             Set olInsp = .GetInspector
             Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
             Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
             oRng.collapse 1
             .Display
             OutMail.HTMLBody = emailText 
             oRng.Paste
         End With
         Set OutMail = Nothing
         Set OutApp = Nothing
         Set olInsp = Nothing
         Set wdDoc = Nothing
         Set oRng = Nothing
    End Sub
```

It gives object required on line pickedName = .Value - if i eliminate the line it will give the same at line emailAddress = namesRng.Offset ...  I thing is a problem with   With ComboBox1 - if i eliminate with , it will generate an email but without the to, subject and text added to it.

Comment: at a quick glance: change `With ComboBox1` with `With .ComboBox1` (a dot missing). then you dim `Dim sourceWS As Object` and then use `Set sourceWH =...`, so try dimming `Dim sourceWH As Object`. But you'd better get the habit of using `Option Explicit` at the very top of every module to force yourself to declare all variables: this will put in some extra work but you'll be rewarded with tons of more control over what your writing!

Comment: Hi, now it works. I will test the code better on the morrow and let you know if is good. Thank you.